# How is the IoU calculated for multiple bounding box predictions in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

How is the IoU metric calculated for multiple bounding box predictions in Tensorflow Object Detection API ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how TensorFlow does it but here is one way that I recently got it to work since I didn't find  a good solution online. I used numpy matrices to get the IoU, & other metrics (TP, FP, TN, FN) for multi-object detection.

Lets say for this example that your image is 6x6.

```
import cv2

empty_array = np.zeros(36).reshape([6, 6])

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

And you have the ground truth for 2 objects, one in the bottom left of the image and one smaller one in the top right.

```
bbox_actual_obj1 = [[0, 3], [2, 5]] # top left coord & bottom right coord
bbox_actual_obj2 = [[4, 0], [5, 1]]
```

Using OpenCV, you can add these objects to a copy of the empty image array.

```
actual = empty.copy()
actual = cv2.rectangle(
    actual,
    bbox_actual_obj1[0],
    bbox_actual_obj1[1],
    1,
    -1
)
actual = cv2.rectangle(
    actual,
    bbox_actual_obj2[0],
    bbox_actual_obj2[1],
    1,
    -1
)

array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Now let's say that below are our predicted bounding boxes:

```
bbox_pred_obj1 = [[1, 3], [3, 5]] # top left coord & bottom right coord
bbox_pred_obj2 = [[3, 0], [5, 2]]
```

Now we do the same thing as above but change the value we assign within the array.

```
pred = empty.copy()
pred = cv2.rectangle(
    pred,
    bbox_person2_car1[0],
    bbox_person2_car1[1],
    2,
    -1
)
pred = cv2.rectangle(
    pred,
    bbox_person2_car2[0],
    bbox_person2_car2[1],
    2,
    -1
)

array([[0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
       [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
       [0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.],
       [0., 2., 2., 2., 0., 0.]])
```

If we convert these arrays to matrices and add them, we get the following result

```
actual_matrix = np.matrix(actual)
pred_matrix = np.matrix(pred)
combined = actual_matrix + pred_matrix

matrix([[0., 0., 0., 2., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 3., 3.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 2., 2.],
        [1., 3., 3., 2., 0., 0.],
        [1., 3., 3., 2., 0., 0.],
        [1., 3., 3., 2., 0., 0.]])
```

Now all we need to do is count the amount of each number in the combined matrix to get the TP, FP, TN, FN rates.

```
combined = np.squeeze(
    np.asarray(
        pred_matrix + actual_matrix
    )
)
unique, counts = np.unique(combined, return_counts=True)
zipped = dict(zip(unique, counts))

{0.0: 15, 1.0: 3, 2.0: 8, 3.0: 10}
```

Legend:

- **True Negative**: 0
- **False Negative**: 1
- **False Positive**: 2
- **True Positive/Intersection**: 3
- **Union**: 1 + 2 + 3

IoU: 0.48 `10/(3 + 8 + 10)`
Precision: 0.56 `10/(10 + 8)`
Recall: 0.77 `10/(10 + 3)`
F1: 0.65 `10/(10 + 0.5 * (3 + 8))`

Answer (score -1):

Each bounding box around an object has an IoU (intersection over union) with the ground-truth box of that object. It is calculated by dividing the common area (overlap) between the predicted bounding box and the actual correct (ground-truth box) by the cumulative area of the two boxes. After calculating all the IoUs for the boxes around an object, the ones with the highest IoU are selected as the result. [Here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/11/07/intersection-over-union-iou-for-object-detection/) it is explained better.

Also you can print the IoU value after [this line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/fe748d4a4a1576b57c279014ac0ceb47344399c4/research/object_detection/core/post_processing.py#L74).